# denormalization(?) of an array of items

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

**SOLVED**

Im trying to denormalization (if this is the right word) an array of items.

Each item has a `qty`. And if an item has f.e. `qty` of 2 then i want to add the same item (a copy) `qty`-times (minus one because 1st is already there).

Example:

```
$items = [
    [
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'qty'  => 2, 
        'items'  => [
            [
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'qty'  => 2,
                'items'  => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 2,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
$expected = [
    [
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'qty'  => 1,
        'items'  => [
            [
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'qty'  => 1,
                'items'  => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'qty'  => 1,
                'items'  => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'qty'  => 1,
        'items'  => [
            [
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'qty'  => 1,
                'items'  => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'qty'  => 1,
                'items'  => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 1,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Script (recursive test):

```
function func(array $items, array &$r)
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $item['qty']; $i++) {
            echo "{$item['name']}\r\n";
            func($item['items'], $r);
        }
    }
}

$r = [];
func($items, $r);
file_put_contents('tmp/_test.php', "<?php return\r\n" . var_export($r, true) . ";");
```

Out:

```
Foo
    Bar
        Baz
        Baz
    Bar
        Baz
        Baz
Foo
    Bar
        Baz
        Baz
    Bar
        Baz
        Baz
```

So far so good.
But i cant get the items correctly sorted into `$r`.

Thanks for any help.

---

Sorry. Solution came to my mind as i re.read my own post.
I was stuck in references. But i just should have returned the items array.

Working script:

```
function func(array $items)
{
    $_items = [];
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $item['qty']; $i++) {
            echo "{$item['name']}\r\n";
            $_items[$n] = $item;
            $_items[$n]['qty'] = 1;
            $_items[$n]['items'] = func($item['items']);
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $_items;
}

$r = func($items);
file_put_contents('tmp/_test.php', "<?php return\r\n" . var_export($r, true) . ";");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compact your solution and eliminate the `$n` counter.
I am starting `$i` from `0` so that only `<` is needed to maintain the logic.
I have used `++$i` instead of `$i++` as a micro-optimization.
I have renamed the function and variables because I found it a little confusing with the variable names being so similar and the function not being descriptive.

I tested this with `2,2,2`, `2,0,2,`, `1,2,3`, and `3,2,1` and my changes have not damaged the result. I think this is as tight as I can make it.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2043992e1c2b063f6d6e3df56e8989237ea53039))

```
function expand(array $array){
    $expanded=[];
    foreach($array as $sub){
        for($i=0; $i<$sub['qty']; ++$i){
            $expanded[]=['name'=>$sub['name'],'qty'=>1,'items'=>expand($sub['items'])];
        }
    }
    return $expanded;
}

$items = [
    [
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'qty'  => 2, 
        'items'  => [
            [
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'qty'  => 2,
                'items'  => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Baz',
                        'qty'  => 2,
                        'items'  => [],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

var_export(expand($items));
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your solution works too. I marked it as accepted answer because its better to read :)